# Installing Qemu from source causing error

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to run Qemu-4.0 installed from source code.

When I run virt-manager to create a VM, I get the following error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-07-19T17:06:35.954242Z qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm: unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2553, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 498, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 434, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3603, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-07-19T17:06:35.954242Z qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm: unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines
```

I configured the Qemu with following command:

```
./../configure --prefix=/usr --enable-spice --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-debug --enable-libssh2

Install prefix    /usr
BIOS directory    /usr/share/qemu
firmware path     /usr/share/qemu-firmware
binary directory  /usr/bin
library directory /usr/lib
module directory  /usr/lib/qemu
libexec directory /usr/libexec
include directory /usr/include
config directory  /usr/etc
local state directory   /usr/var
Manual directory  /usr/share/man
ELF interp prefix /usr/gnemul/qemu-%M
Source path       /home/probir/Downloads/qemu/qemu-4.0.0
GIT binary        git
GIT submodules    
C compiler        cc
Host C compiler   cc
C++ compiler      c++
Objective-C compiler cc
ARFLAGS           rv
CFLAGS            -g 
QEMU_CFLAGS       -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I$(SRC_PATH)/dtc/libfdt -DHAS_LIBSSH2_SFTP_FSYNC  -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -mcx16 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -std=gnu99  -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wendif-labels -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-strong  -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1    -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/spice-server -I/usr/include/spice-1 -I$(SRC_PATH)/capstone/include
LDFLAGS           -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g 
QEMU_LDFLAGS      -L$(BUILD_DIR)/dtc/libfdt 
make              make
install           install
python            python -B (2.7.15+)
slirp support     internal 
smbd              /usr/sbin/smbd
module support    no
host CPU          x86_64
host big endian   no
target list       x86_64-softmmu
gprof enabled     no
sparse enabled    no
strip binaries    no
profiler          no
static build      no
SDL support       no 
SDL image support no
GTK support       yes (3.22.30)
GTK GL support    no
VTE support       no 
TLS priority      NORMAL
GNUTLS support    yes
libgcrypt         no
nettle            yes (3.4)
libtasn1          yes
PAM               no
iconv support     yes
curses support    no
virgl support     no 
curl support      yes
mingw32 support   no
Audio drivers      oss
Block whitelist (rw) 
Block whitelist (ro) 
VirtFS support    yes
Multipath support no
VNC support       yes
VNC SASL support  yes
VNC JPEG support  yes
VNC PNG support   yes
xen support       yes
xen ctrl version  40900
brlapi support    yes
bluez  support    yes
Documentation     yes
PIE               yes
vde support       no
netmap support    no
Linux AIO support yes
ATTR/XATTR support yes
Install blobs     yes
KVM support       yes
HAX support       no
HVF support       no
WHPX support      no
TCG support       yes
TCG debug enabled yes
TCG interpreter   no
malloc trim support yes
RDMA support      no
PVRDMA support    no
fdt support       git
membarrier        no
preadv support    yes
fdatasync         yes
madvise           yes
posix_madvise     yes
posix_memalign    yes
libcap-ng support yes
vhost-net support yes
vhost-crypto support yes
vhost-scsi support yes
vhost-vsock support yes
vhost-user support yes
Trace backends    log
spice support     yes (0.12.13/0.14.0)
rbd support       yes
xfsctl support    yes
smartcard support no
libusb            yes
usb net redir     yes
OpenGL support    no
OpenGL dmabufs    no
libiscsi support  yes
libnfs support    no
build guest agent yes
QGA VSS support   no
QGA w32 disk info no
QGA MSI support   no
seccomp support   yes
coroutine backend ucontext
coroutine pool    yes
debug stack usage no
mutex debugging   yes
crypto afalg      no
GlusterFS support no
gcov              gcov
gcov enabled      no
TPM support       yes
libssh2 support   yes
TPM passthrough   
TPM emulator      
QOM debugging     yes
Live block migration yes
lzo support       yes
snappy support    yes
bzip2 support     yes
lzfse support     no
NUMA host support yes
libxml2           yes
tcmalloc support  no
jemalloc support  no
avx2 optimization yes
replication support yes
VxHS block device no
bochs support     yes
cloop support     yes
dmg support       yes
qcow v1 support   yes
vdi support       yes
vvfat support     yes
qed support       yes
parallels support yes
sheepdog support  yes
capstone          internal
docker            no
libpmem support   no
libudev           no
default devices   yes

NOTE: cross-compilers enabled:  'cc'
```

Is it that I missed enabling any configuration while installing Qemu?

Comment: The error suggests your machine doesn't support KVM.

Comment: With kvm-ok I can see that it supports KVM
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
-----------
$ egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo
6

Comment: Additionally, I can run qemu-kvm that I install with apt-get. But I am missing something while installing from source.

Comment: While configuring qemu it says: KVM support       yes